# Moto G3 hangs at boot after rooting

Tags: rooting, boot, motorola-moto-g3

I have a Moto G3 and I have just rooted it. When I rebooted it, it is taking too much time for rebooting. It's nearly passed 45 minutes since I rebooted.

Comment: What Android version and root method did you use? If SuperSU or Magisk what version? If you used any other method it will fail. The Moto G3 can be tricky to root if you don't have the correct versions or use the right method (it is often more complex than just flashing a ZIP file).

Answer (score 1):

This is common with this device if you didn't do a manual systemless root with SuperSU... To fix it perform the following steps, assuming you have an unlocked bootloader and the latest TWRP 3.1.1 installed.

1. Download the latest SuperSU from [here](https://download.chainfire.eu/supersu/) (official source)
2. Start TWRP and copy the SuperSU zip file to the device
3. In TWRP, go to Home, Advanced, then Terminal
4. Enter `echo SYSTEMLESS=true>>/data/.supersu` EXACTLY as shown and press Enter
5. Enter `cat /data/.supersu` to verify the output is `SYSTEMLESS=true`
6. Exit the terminal and press Home
7. Install the latest ZIP from Chainfire
8. Reboot. The device should not take more than 15 minutes to boot

Although I haven't updated it in a while, [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/guide-how-to-root-moto-g-2015-model-t3448572) is the full guide with explanations of each piece.

If you used Magisk, no special preparations are necessary if you are using a current version, just flash, install Magisk Manager, and enjoy.